# Initializing a DVC repository throws an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, version-control, dvc

I'm trying to use [DVC](https://dvc.org/) and I'm following this kaggle tutorial as explained in this [notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/kurianbenoy/introduction-to-data-version-control-dvc) . Whenever I try to use the command `! dvc init`, I get the following error:

```
'dvc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've installed and reinstalled dvc. I'm using python 3.6 and windows 8.1.

Comment: How are you installing DVC? Please follow https://dvc.org/doc/install

Comment: Also, that Kaggle is probably outdated. I rec the ofifical DVC start guide: https://dvc.org/doc/start

Answer (score 2):

Even after manually installing dvc I ran into this error. Closing and reopening the command prompt resolved it. Specifically, since I was using the Anaconda command prompt, I had to close the prompt and Anaconda, and then open Anaconda and a new prompt.

Comment: I was using VSCode and had to do the same thing with the terminal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was pip-installing dvc. This, in my experience doesn't work very well and gives various errors at different stages. Instead, I manually installed dvc and added it to PATH variables in windows. Works like a charm :)